# Performance Measurement of a central log management system

Tags: performance, testing, logging, performance-testing, monitor

I been working on a private project which is capturing events from different systems, now my question is as I am using my Q to receive and process these events but still I have a confusion about its performance measures and parameters as events are being queued on collection time and my Q structure is a bit flexible how to measure the performance of such systems?

Note: I am a beginner to such systems, this is my first experience developing such system.

Comment: I guess one metric might be the number of events that you can log per second.